# Pandas: Select rows where a number of strings appear more than once

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data and want to find a count of rows where a certain set of values appears multiple times.

```
date   page1   page2   page3   page4
1/2001 entered toyota  NaN     NaN
1/2001 entered ford    NaN     NaN
1/2001 entered honda   ford    left
1/2001 entered ford    toyota  left 
1/2001 entered toyota  ford    left
1/2001 entered index   photo    left
```

What I am trying to do is find the number of columns where a vehicle appears more than twice (>= 2). So given the above data, there are two rows where a vehicle appears twice.

So in the previous example, I'd have the following.

```
honda ford 1
ford toyota 1
toyota ford 1
```

I thought about attacking this via pandasql, but I'm at a total loss as to how I'd even approach this (newbie here). Can anyone point me to some suggestions or what I should consider.

Also, the second part of what I want to do is find a count of values based upon the combinations. That can be done as follows, but how can it be done via Pandas directly.

```
q  = """
SELECT Path_1, Path_2, COUNT(*) FROM df
GROUP BY Path_1, Path_2;
"""
print ps.sqldf(q, locals())
```

Comment: does the order matter?  e.g., is 'honda ford' the same as 'ford honda'?

Comment: the order doesn't matter

Comment: also, how do you, from your input, conclude that `1/2001 entered honda   ford    left` has >= 3 vehicles in it?

Comment: I guess I meant >= 2...basically, if two or more vehicles appear in the path columns, I'm looking for a count of those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you can use this kinda math here:

```
vehicles = {'ford', 'honda', 'toyota', 'steve_urkel_car'} #etc
df[df.isin(vehicles).sum(1) >= 2]
```